# My numpy code displaying this error, can anyone see what it is saying?

Tags: numpy

```
  def generateHand():
    cardOne = ("one", "two", 'three', "four", "five", "six", 'seven', "eight", "nine", "10", 
    "jack", "queen", "king")
     suits = ["spades", "diamonds", "hearts", "clubs"]
    suitUse = np.random.choice(suits, 1)
    cardOneVar = np.random.choice(cardOne, 1)

   print ("A" + cardOneVar + "Of" + suitUse)
```

This code is generating this error.

> File "main.py", line 25, in generateHand
> print ("A" + cardOneVar + "Of" + suitUse)
> numpy.core._exceptions.UFuncTypeError: ufunc 'add' did not contain a loop with signature
> matching
> types (dtype('<U1'), dtype('<U5')) -> None
> 

Does anybody know what the issue is? The error began after I changed the code to print writing and `cardOneVar` rather than just the suit variable. The indent errors are because of the issues with copy pasting, they are not in the code.

Comment: U1 and U5 are string dtypes.  You can't add them.  Python strings join with'+' but numpy string dtype arrays don't.

Comment: Try `f"A {cardOneVar} Of {suitUse}'`

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the return type of np.random.choice(), which is an np.ndarray, is incompatible with concatenation. Try using:

```
suitUse = np.random.choice(suits, 1)[0]
cardOneVar = np.random.choice(cardOne, 1)[0]
```

this will make the types of suitUse and cardOneVar strings instead, by choosing the first (and only) value in the ndarray.

Answer (score 0):

```
In [119]: suits = ["spades", "diamonds", "hearts", "clubs"]
```

The result of your `choice` is a 1d, 1 element, array with string dtype:

```
In [120]: x = np.random.choice(suits,1)
In [121]: x
Out[121]: array(['spades'], dtype='<U8')
```

It can be formatted with:

```
In [122]: print(f'Of {x}')
Of ['spades']
```

or without the brackets:

```
In [123]: print(f'Of {x[0]}')
Of spades
```

If we omit the size value, the result is string "scalar", that does 'add':

```
In [124]: x = np.random.choice(suits)
In [125]: x
Out[125]: 'spades'
In [126]: 'Of '+x
Out[126]: 'Of spades'
In [127]: print(f'Of {x}')
Of spades
In [128]: type(x)
Out[128]: numpy.str_
```